# Eth2.0 and Eth1.0 contracts in the future

Tags: solidity, eth-2.0, beacon-chain

We are all waiting for the new eth.  But I can't figure out if blockchains will be interoperable in the distant future?  Imagine that I have created a TimeLockContract that will be exposed in 8 years.  Is this a problem for me?

Answer (score 0):

No you won't see a difference! Practically speaking, as long as you weren't a minor in Eth1 you won't notice the change to Eth2. The slight change that you might notice is that instead of a block every 14 seconds it will be 12 seconds.